# ¿Deseo saber si estoy adquieriendo bien el dato?

Tags: php, mysqli

Muy buenas con todos, tengo una duda que me mata la cabeza y ya llevo varios días, estoy realizando una consulta con un join, el motivo de todo esto, es que necesito agarrar un dato en especifico de una tabla en especifico.

Explicación

Tengo estas dos tablas, la una que es sistemascomentarios es donde se visualiza que elige el cliente  y la tabla Sistema es un option select que le muestra al cliente que puede seleccionar, ambas estan enlazadas con un FK.
[image: muestra las tablas]

No se como hacer que cuando el cliente elija, algo dentro del select, este me mande el valor, que seria usuarios. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*EJEMPLO*
Si el cliente elige la palabra **circulo**, me tiene que dar el valor de 3, que es a lo que equivale el circulo.

ESTE ES MI CODIGO:

```
<?php 
    include("includes/db.php");
?>

<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Select</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
           
   <h2> Sube Tu Cuota </h2>

    <?php 
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT nombre, usuarios FROM sistema "; 
        $res = $conexion->query($query);
        $option = '';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $option .= "<option value=\"$row[nombre]\">$row[nombre] </option>" ; 
        } 
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="insertar.php">
        <input type="text" name="com" placeholder="comentarios">
            <select name="shape" >
                <option value=""> Select a shape </option>
                <?php echo $option; ?> 

            </select>
            
            <input type="submit" name="registrar">
            <input type="submit" value="consultar" name="btn-2">
    </form>
    <?php 
    
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `sistemascomentarios` SC
        JOIN `sistema` S 
        ON SC.idSistema = S.idSistema)";

        $res = $conexion->query($query);
        $table ='<tr>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $table ='<p>';
            $table .= "<td>$row[usuarios] </td>";
            $table .='</tr>';
        }
        $table .='</p>';

        $res = $table .= "<td>$row[usuarios]</td>";
    ?>

    <tr>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
        
        <?php echo  $res; ?>

        <?php 

            $variable = $res ;
        ?>

        <?php 
        
        ?>
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Es lo que tengo por el momento, ademas lo que necesito es que esa variable usuarios quede como numerico, porque me faltan hacer unos operaciones mas con esa misma variable que es de usuarios

Comment: porque los select tienen usuarios? y porque el `idSistema` es una palabra y no un `numero`? lo que te recomiendo es hacer las tabla selecte con `idSitema` numerico auto increment

Comment: Esos son los valores de cada opción, El idsistema es una palabra para concatenar con un FK con la variable de la otra tabla, eso esta ingresado, lo que deseo saber es como obtener el valor que se observa en usuarios al momento que el cliente escoja alguna de las opciones. Muchas gracias por la recomendacion.